# Are there laundry services or shops in Bangkok, Thailand?

Tags: thailand, hygiene, bangkok

In [Ko Chang](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Chang), laundry services can be found in any street, around 25 baht per kg.

In [Bangkok](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bangkok), I am unable to find any such service. I could only find hotel services that charge 25 baht per pair of socks.

Are there any reasonable laundry services, or self-laundry shops, in Bangkok? If yes, what is a convenient way to find them?

Comment: At least the Khao San Road area is full of laundries, and 25/kg sounds about right. I was there about 2.5/3 months ago. Bangkok is a huge city though so maybe you should tell us which part if you're not near Khao San.

Comment: Yes they are. Almost every where in places where foreigners stay. They are quite cheap and fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a list of laundry service providers in Bangkok. You can look over it. I hope it will help you to find your nearest service provider.

http://bangkokscoop.com/about-2/services/laundry-and-dry-cleaning/

Answer (score 1):

There is a new 24-hour laundry service called [Wahsbox24](https://www.washbox24.com/web/index.php?location). Now I don't live in Bangkok so I have never used it before. The price is quite steep for 20 baht per piece! But they do pick-up & delivery so it can be good for really busy time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a coin op laundry near Taksin Skytrain.  Just down the Soi opposite Robinsons Department store.  20 THB for 8 Kilos.  Bring your own detergent.  Wash takes just over 1 hour.